# What's the sql exception error number if the maximum limit of the database has been reached

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlexception, sql-server-2005-express

For example SQL Server 2005 Express has a limit of 4gb on the database size, and it has been reached after cumulative inserts of data. What will be the corresponding error number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these are the error codes you are looking for.

Error 1827:

> "CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting
>   cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 4096 MB
>   per database. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1827)"

Error 1105:

> "Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.t' in database 'ext' because
>   the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting
>   unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional
>   files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in
>   the filegroup."

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you  sir. Do the log file (LDF) that comes along with the data-(MDF) file have limits too? what are your suggestions if the mdf file limit has been reached? Is archiving/moving old data to archive database recommended?

Answer (score 1):

> Msg 1827, Level 16, State 4, Server SOMECOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS, Line 1
>   CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting
>   cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 4096 MB
>   per database.